# ng2-file-upload response scope

Tags: typescript, angular6

i want to access the response out of onCompleteItem..

How can i access the onitemcomplete response outside of Uploader.onitemcomplete

i have tried defining array outside function and then push the value in the function but it also not working

here is my code...

```
add(data,action){
this.data.loader = true;

this.uploader.uploadAll();
this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };
this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {

  this.data.dp = JSON.parse(response);
 **HERE IS THE RESPONSE**  
 };
  //console.log(this.data.dp);
 var frmData = JSON.stringify({'fname': data.fname,'mname':data.mname,'lname':data.lname, 
'contact':data.phone, 'email':data.email, 'address':data.address, 'country':data.country, 'state':data.state, 
'pin':data.pin, 'uimg':**WANT TO  ACCESS IT HERE**});
 console.log(this.data.headers);
 if(action == 'Save'){

 this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/api/account/register",frmData,this.options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.data.loader = false;
          this.data.message = data.message;

        this.snackBar.open('Registered Successfully.', '', {
          duration: 3000,
        });
      }

    else {
      this.snackBar.open(data.message, '', {
          duration: 3000,
        });
    }

            this.data.fname = '';
    this.data.mname = '';
    this.data.lname = '';
    this.data.phone = '';
    this.data.email = '';
    this.data.address = '';
    this.data.pin = '';
    this.data.state = '';
    this.data.country = '';


      },error => {
      this.data.message = 'Error';
      });


  }
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the response and when?

Comment: in response i have a image url and i want to post that url when the registration i.e when add() triggers @toskv

Comment: onComplete is asynchronous, that means the code inside can be executed at any later point in time. My suggestion is to move the code after it to it's own class method, and call that from inside onComplete.

Comment: yes @toskv i also tried that but if image is not selected then the methods from add() is not triggering...

Comment: that's a completely different issue from what you have described though.

Answer (score 0):

The code in onComplete executes asynchronously. If you want the code after it to be executed after onComplete is called you need to move it to it's own method and call it.

It would look something like this:

```js
class Component {
  private data: any;
  private uploader: any;
  add(data, action) {
    this.data.loader = true;

    this.uploader.uploadAll();
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
      file.withCredentials = false;
    };
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {

      this.data.dp = JSON.parse(response);
      // when on complete ends we set the avatar
      this.setAvatar(data, action);
    };

  }

  private setAvatar(data, action) {
    //console.log(this.data.dp);
    var frmData = JSON.stringify({
      'fname': data.fname,
      'mname': data.mname,
      'lname': data.lname,
      'contact': data.phone,
      'email': data.email,
      'address': data.address,
      'country': data.country,
      'state': data.state,
      'pin': data.pin,
      'uimg': ** WANT TO ACCESS IT HERE **
    });
    console.log(this.data.headers);
    if (action == 'Save') {

      this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/api/account/register", frmData, this.options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data.loader = false;
            this.data.message = data.message;

            this.snackBar.open('Registered Successfully.', '', {
              duration: 3000,
            });
          } else {
            this.snackBar.open(data.message, '', {
              duration: 3000,
            });
          }

          this.data.fname = ''; this.data.mname = ''; this.data.lname = ''; this.data.phone = ''; this.data.email = ''; this.data.address = ''; this.data.pin = ''; this.data.state = ''; this.data.country = '';


        }, error => {
          this.data.message = 'Error';
        });


  }
}
```